# open-source alternative framework for Android

Tags: android, mobile, frameworks

After about two months of Java development for Android, I still don't like the API, so I would like to switch to another framework.

I also want it to be open source, to compile to native packages and, if possible, not dependent on Eclipse.

My OS is Debian GNU/Linux.

I already tried several: PhoneGap (requires Eclipse), Appcelerator Titanium (non-open source license), and Python4Android (not native).

Comment: If by "Notepad" you mean "Vim" and by "gcc" you mean "ant", I already do.

Comment: unless you know any way to write C code for Android using gcc, in which case I would be glad to know about it

Comment: Android NDK is all about C/C++ and GCC. The native library is rather limited though - you're expected to call back to Java for almost everything.

Comment: PhoneGap does not require Eclipse. Titanium Mobile is under [the Apache License 2.0](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/LICENSE).

Comment: To download Titanium software, I have to accept this agreement: http://www.appcelerator.com/legal/appexplore-agreement (read paragraph 10)

Comment: I followed the PhoneGap tutorial (even if it asks for Eclipse): http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html and I get an error, even if I exactly do what they tell me to do. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.progval.android.testapp.MainActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Please try Sencha touch 2. Open source, compatible with phonegap and supports cross platform development.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out Mono? Create Android apps in c#/.net but still have access to native api!

[monoforandroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid)

Comment: It first looked great, but it only works on Windows and Mac OSX